# Problems on making a countdown button for WP8, using C# and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am developing for Windows Phone 8 apps(silverlight), and I'm trying to make a button on a page for registration that it countdowns on its content after clicking, which is used to getting SMS Verification code and to prevent malicious requests.
I would like it to be like this:

Original button:

[Send Me Verification Code]

After Clicked:

[29s remaining...] <---it countdowns on its content.

After Countdown completed:

[Send me again]

And also, I would like it to be asynchronous,for I have to make HTTPrequests after that.

This is the code I write but it gives me a CS0120 Error, and after creating an instance of the class it compiles, but doesn't work and throw Exceptions.

```
 public partial class Register : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Thread newThread;
    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Register iregister = new Register();             
        //newThread = new Thread(iregister.SetText);
        //I've tried these but no luck..

        newThread = new Thread(Register.SetText);
    }

    public static void SetText()
    {
        int i = 30;
       // Register iregister = new Register();
        while (i > 0)
        {

           btn_sendVeri.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { btn_sendVeri.Content=   i + "seconds remaining"; }); //**CS0120**
            i--; 
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }


    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //btn_sendVeri.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        newThread.Start(); 

          //Put httprequests here
    }
```

the btn_sendVeri is a button defined in the XAML.

```
<Button x:Name="btn_sendVeri" Content="Send Verification Code" Width="245" Height="85" Click="Button_Click" Background="#33cc66"/>
```

How can I fix my code?
Thanks for Helping .:)

Comment: Don't know whats causing the issue, but just a suggestion, wouldn't it be easier to use Task instead of Thread?

Comment: Do you know why it gives me a CS0120 error? (there are Wavy lines under btn_sendVeri in the line. `btn_sendVeri.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() { btn_sendVeri.Content=   i + "seconds remaining"; });`

Comment: @adminSoftDK tried but same problem. Maybe there's something else in my code is incorrect :(

Comment: Use Task instead of thread.. It would be easy..